# Notice: Array to string conversion when call method dynamically from array value

Tags: php

> index.php

```
include_once "system/libs/Main.php";
include_once "system/libs/FController.php";

$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = rtrim($url,'/');
$url =explode("/", $url);

include('app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php');

$ctlr = new $url[0]();
$ctlr->$url[1]();
```

======================

If echo from array index it is Ok.
and when I call method directly it also Ok.

but when I call method dynamically from array index value it says:
"Notice: Array to string conversion".

Comment: where is the array index here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the `$url[1]` with brackets (but be aware executing PHP by $_GET isn't the best for security).

Your code should then look like this:

```
$ctlr->{$url[1]}();
```

Comment: Thanks for response. it works! :)
By the way, what should I use instead of of $_GET in this case as I want to  use mvc structure? I pass all controllers, models and methods in this way.

Comment: @Forkan Instead of executing the function dynamicly using $_GET, you could use a `switch($url[1])` and then make a `case "method"` for each method would be much more secure thought the method you used might result to code arbitrary execution 
(aka you could execute code on your machine using a get request). 
Exept that, your code is fine :)